# Polar forms of algebraic curves & surfaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, surfaces, plane-curves

A paper I'm reading says the following ...

> With homogeneous coordinates $\mathbf{x} = [x,y,z,w]$, let $F(\mathbf{x}) = 0$ be the equation of a surface of degree $n$. The **first polar form** of  $F(\mathbf{x})$ at the **pole** $\mathbf{a} = [a,b,c,h]$ is defined as
>   $$
> F^1(\mathbf{x}) = \frac1n(aF_x + bF_y + cF_z + hF_w)
> $$

And then, later, there's a similar definition ...

> Let $\mathbf{p}(x)$ be a polynomial curve of degree $n$ and let $\mathbf{p}(x,w)$ denote its homogeneous form. Its **first polar** with respect to the **pole** $x_1$ is defined by
>   $$
> \mathbf{p}^1(x_1 \,|\,x) = \frac1n(x_1\mathbf{p}_x + \mathbf{p}_w)
> $$

The paper says these concepts are "well-known in algebraic geometry". I'm having trouble understanding what these things mean geometrically. Could someone explain, or provide a reference, please. I'd like the explanation or reference to be something simple and concrete in 2D or 3D space, please; abstraction and generality probably won't help me.

Comment: Hey, welcome back to MSE (+1)

Comment: Welcome again, Please don't quit entirely,keep a low key on  topics of your interest, my 2 cents.

Comment: Since there were no answers here, I asked the same question at MathOverflow, and got some useful info: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/235094/polars-of-algebraic-curves-and-surfaces